# simple loops involving error "local variable referenced before assignment..."

Tags: python

Python:
I have researched a lot into this, but as a beginner I don't understand the solutions, let alone apply them to my simple problem:

```
def min_max(xs):
    xs = []
    for i in xs:
        y = (min, max)
    return y
```

"local variable 'y' referenced before assignment"

I don't understand why this does NOT work!!
I've defined Y in the line before return, i know there is another way to do it, but i really need to know why this method is wrong!
Thanks!

Comment: Google "python variable scope" to get your answer.

Answer (score 5):

assuming that min and max are defined somewhere else....

The loop `for i in xs` will go around once for each item in `xs`. Since xs is empty, the loop will not run at all. So, y is never set.

Comment: Do you use `print y` to see the result anywhere to test it?  It's possible you may not be seeing anything because there may not be something to see.